# Direct2D refuses to draw a bitmap onto a window, fails silently

Tags: c++, winapi, user-interface, embedded-resource, direct2d

I am trying to draw a 128x128 bitmap onto a window with Direct2D. However, nothing shows up and `EndDraw()` doesn't return any errors.

This is my `WM_PAINT` code:

```
case WM_PAINT:
        D2D1_RECT_F testd2dbuttonrect;

        mainwRT->BeginDraw();
        mainwRT->SetTransform( D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Identity() );

        testd2dbutton.pd2drectgm->GetRect( &testd2dbuttonrect );
        mainwRT->FillRectangle( &testd2dbuttonrect, pSolidBrush );

        //This is where I'm trying to draw my bitmap
        mainwRT->FillRectangle( D2D1::RectF(0.0f,0.0f,127.0f,127.0f), pBgndBrush );

        errmsg = mainwRT->EndDraw();
        if( !SUCCEEDED(errmsg) )
            printf("EndDraw() error: %d\r\n", errmsg );
        break;
```

I suspect it might be because the bitmap data I've loaded from a Visual Studio resource is rubbish, but I have no way of knowing since nothing fails and gives error messages. This is the code I used to load an `ID2D1Bitmap` from a resource:

```
int LoadBitmapFromResource( IWICImagingFactory *pImageFactory, ID2D1RenderTarget *pRT, int resID, ID2D1Bitmap **ppD2DBitmap )
{
    int errmsg;

    HBITMAP hbitmap;
    WICBitmapAlphaChannelOption wicalpha;
    IWICBitmap *pwicbitmap;
    IWICBitmapSource *pconvertedwicbitmap;
    IWICFormatConverter *pConverter;

    ID2D1Factory *d2dfactory;
    D2D1_BITMAP_PROPERTIES d2dbp;
    D2D1_PIXEL_FORMAT d2dpf;
    FLOAT dpiX;
    FLOAT dpiY;

    hbitmap = LoadBitmap( GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCEW(resID) );
    wicalpha = WICBitmapUseAlpha;

    errmsg = pImageFactory->CreateBitmapFromHBITMAP( hbitmap, NULL, wicalpha, &pwicbitmap );
    if( !SUCCEEDED(errmsg) )
    {
        printf("LoadBitmapFromResource::CreateBitmapFromHBITMAP() error: %x\r\n", errmsg );
        return errmsg;
    }

    errmsg = pImageFactory->CreateFormatConverter( &pConverter );
    if( !SUCCEEDED(errmsg) )
    {
        printf("LoadBitmapFromResource::CreateFormatConverter() error: %x\r\n", errmsg );
        return errmsg;
    }

    d2dpf.format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
    d2dpf.alphaMode = D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_PREMULTIPLIED;
    pRT->GetFactory( &d2dfactory );
    d2dfactory->GetDesktopDpi( &dpiX, &dpiY );
    d2dbp.pixelFormat = d2dpf;
    d2dbp.dpiX = dpiX;
    d2dbp.dpiY = dpiY;

    pConverter->Initialize( pwicbitmap, GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppPBGRA, WICBitmapDitherTypeNone, NULL, 0.0f, WICBitmapPaletteTypeMedianCut );
    if( !SUCCEEDED(errmsg) )
    {
        printf("LoadBitmapFromResource::Initialize() error: %x\r\n", errmsg );
        return errmsg;
    }

    errmsg = WICConvertBitmapSource( GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppPBGRA, pwicbitmap, &pconvertedwicbitmap );
    if( !SUCCEEDED(errmsg) )
    {
        printf("LoadBitmapFromResource::WICConvertBitmapSource() error: %x\r\n", errmsg );
        return errmsg;
    }

    errmsg = pRT->CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap( pconvertedwicbitmap, &d2dbp, ppD2DBitmap );
    if( !SUCCEEDED(errmsg) )
    {
        printf("LoadBitmapFromResource::CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap() error: %x\r\n", errmsg );
        return errmsg;
    }

    pConverter->Release();
    pwicbitmap->Release();
    DeleteObject( hbitmap );

    return 0;
}
```

I am using C++ with native WinAPI in Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: I don't know DirectX, but in graphics, when you don't see anything at all, it is possible that you have "double buffer" enabled and you are not swapping buffers. Is that the case?

Comment: @Shahbaz I don't think that's the case...I am drawing another solid colour rectangle that shows up just fine. I think Direct2D takes care of it as it's supposed to be used for desktop interfaces as opposed to complex graphics rendering that Direct3D is used for.

Answer (score 1):

I think you still have to use the classic BeginPaint() in WM_PAINT, then do your D2D rendering, and then call EndPaint(). That's what my code does, and I think it's what the MSDN sample code gizmos do as well.

Comment: The MSDN samples that I've studied do not use BeginPaint/EndPaint.  Instead they simply call ValidateRect after painting the window with Direct2D.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue when load bitmap from resource and D2D having problem when run CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap. Helped with my co-worker, the key issue is to use WICBitmapIgnoreAlpha as Bitmap has no Alpha (at least my BITMAP in resource has no Alpha).

And even you no need converter, just simple code like

```
hbitmap = LoadBitmap(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(resID) );
if (hbitmap==0)
{
    SafeRelease(&pImageFactory);
    return nullptr;
}

hr = pImageFactory->CreateBitmapFromHBITMAP( hbitmap, NULL, wicalpha, &pwicbitmap );
if( !SUCCEEDED(hr) )
{
    DeleteObject( hbitmap );
    SafeRelease(&pImageFactory);
    return nullptr;
}
ID2D1Bitmap* ppD2DBitmap=nullptr;
hr = pRT->CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap( pwicbitmap, &ppD2DBitmap );
```

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into a very similar issue, so I figured I'd leave my solution here: if you're trying to draw something using direct2d and nothing is showing up (but no errors are reported) you may have forgotten to resize your render target in the WM_SIZE message. If you don't do this and also don't initialize the render target with the screen size, you'll have a render target of size zero, which will simply fail to draw anything, even screen clear operations will fail.

Answer (score 0):

The way to debug this is to use various API lock calls to get a pointer to the image data, then check the image data, either via the debugger or printf, to verify the data is what you expect.

There's different Lock calls available for the HBITMAP and the D2D surface, but the same idea can be used.  You should be able to narrow down where you're getting the bad data.